# Android studio emulator Back Button

Tags: android

In my Android Studio emulator, the hardware back button is not working: when we go for one window, there is no option to return back. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Use ESC Button... May be you havent enabled while creating emulator

Comment: Tank you thats working

Answer (score 1):

Use ESC Button to navigate back in Emulator